# C# Items don't appear in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a simple tasklist application as an excercise in Windows Forms and C#, both of which I am very new to. I'm using the following code to try to display the process IDs in a listView (that I've made in the design view in Visual Studio) but when I run it the items don't appear.

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var currentWindow = new taskMngrWndw();
        Application.Run(currentWindow);
        Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process proc in processList)
        {
            string processID = Convert.ToString(proc.Id);
            currentWindow.taskView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(processID));
        }
        currentWindow.taskView.Refresh();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you traced it? why is the process list portion in this area?

Comment: @BugFinder like I said, I'm really, really green behind the ears so I'm not sure what trace means and I thought this was the best place for it - should it be in the form's .cs file instead?

Comment: Set your ListView View property to "Details"

Comment: You should not add code to the `Main()` method in a Windows Forms application (unless you know exactly what you're doing). If you want your code to initialize the items of a `ListView` in a `Form`, then add that code to the form itself (i.e. like in the form constructor, or the `Load` event of the form).

Comment: @LocEngineer already done

Comment: step through your app - using the tools on debug ..

Comment: I moved everything save the Application statements to the form's code but now currentWindow is undefined and I'm not sure what to do about it

Comment: If you are in the code of the form class, then you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the current `Form` instance.

Comment: @bassfader that's the solution, thanks!

Comment: Actually, using `this` is redundant too, just use `taskView.Items...`

Comment: Yeah, it corrected me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this line doesn't return until the main form is closed (i.e. your app is exiting):

```
Application.Run(currentWindow);
```

So the code to fill the list view only runs after the the form is dismissed and closed. Instead, move that code into the form, for example in the Form `Load` event:

```
private void taskMngrWndw_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillProcesses();
}

private void FillProcesses()
{
    Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process proc in processList)
    {
        string processID = Convert.ToString(proc.Id);
        taskView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(processID));
    }
}
```